# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ElastixImageFilter'

Tags: python, python-2.7, registration, itk, simpleitk

I have followed the `SimpleElastix` installation in [the link](https://simpleelastix.readthedocs.io/GettingStarted.html). When I run the following command to install the python wrapper of SimpleElastix, it is successfully running and can import the packages:

```
sudo python Packaging/setup.py install
```

and I can import the packages and use the function as follows:

```
user@user-XPS-8920:~/softwares/SimpleElastix/build/SimpleITK-build/Wrapping/Python$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import SimpleITK as sitk
>>> elastixImageFilter = sitk.ElastixImageFilter()
>>>
```

However, once I exit from the python terminal to the bash, and changing to python terminal command line again, it does not recognize the function:

```
user@user-XPS-8920:~/workspace/registration$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import SimpleITK as sitk
>>> elastixImageFilter = sitk.ElastixImageFilter()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ElastixImageFilter'
>>>
```

Do you have any idea to help with this? What is the reason?

Comment: In both examples, add `print(sitk.__file__)` after the import to ensure you are actually importing the exact same module.

Comment: It appears that the method works when you are inside the SimpleITK directory, but not when outside of it. Installing SimpleITK with pip might fix this issue.    `pip install SimpleITK` And make sure the version of pip you are using corresponds to your python2.7 by running `pip --version`

Answer (score 1):

Check the directory you were running the code from `~/softwares/SimpleElastix/build/SimpleITK-build/Wrapping/Python` in first example and `~/workspace/registration` in second. Maybe this is not added to the PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Check if the module exists in your path variable using `sys.path`.

Comment: Thank you, but adding the path to the `sys.path` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` did not work

Answer (score 1):

I could only solve this issue by adding the following path to the `.bashrc` on the terminal

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/user/softwares/SimpleElastix/build/SimpleITK-build/Wrapping/Python
```